# How to get the end of a catch block with Soot?

Tags: java, try-catch, soot

I am trying to do java bytecode analysis for try/catch with Soot. I can get the statements in try block and the first statement of the catch block, but I can't know where the catch block end. How can I get the end statement?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more tricky, it needs to be computed. The statement succeeding the catch block is going to be a "post-dominator" of all the statements within the catch block. You can use this class to find post-dominators: https://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/doc/soot/toolkits/graph/MHGPostDominatorsFinder.htm